# A simple C MySQL client - direct access safe enough?

Tags: sql, c, client

I want to develop a (very) simple MySQL client application in C, for Ubuntu Linux. The functionality for now should include just adding new records to the database (on a remote server). I've experimented with the MySQL API and wrote a simple program that does this locally, however I'm not sure if that's the way to go with a remote database (on a server). Should I just directly connect? Is that safe? Or maybe I should use cURL to access a PHP script which would then process the queries for me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fine and perfectly safe to directly connect using C, that is what the API is there for. Remember the usual rules apply when handling user input, validate heavily and escape strings, but this is not something unique to C.

If you feel you'd rather work in MySQL with PHP you can always output data in an easier to use format to work with in C and save yourself having to use the MySQL library, it depends on your performance requirements as to what you do I guess. Personally I got tired of building raw SQL queries and models in C very quickly. MySQL++ (C++) can alleviate the pain somewhat, but C/C++ are just not as nice as other languages for this kind of thing.

You state that it is a remote server. If you have already built a lot of infrastructure in PHP I'd be inclined to use that and build an interface between your client application and the database. Of course what you do depends entirely on the **requirements of your application**.